# I'm having trouble evaluating this contour integral.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm having trouble evaluating this contour integral.
More specifically evaluating the residue at z=0.
Thank you in advance!

$$ \oint_{|z|=3} \frac{1}{2-z} e^{\frac{1}{z}} \,dz $$

Comment: Have you tried the change of variables $w=\frac1z$?

Comment: Take @GregMartin's advice, but bear in mind it reverses the contour's direction, cancelling the $-$ sign in $dz=-dw/w^2$.

Comment: I guess another way is to write $z=9/\bar z$ on the contour and then move the conjugate outside the integral by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that since $|z|=3,$ you will have that $$\frac1{2-z}e^{\frac1{z}}=\frac1{\frac2{z}-1}\frac{e^{\frac1{z}}}{z}=-\frac1{1-\frac2{z}}\frac{e^{\frac1{z}}}{z}=-\frac{e^{\frac1{z}}}{z}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^m}{z^m}=-e^{\frac1{z}}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^m}{z^{m+1}}=-\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^m\frac{e^{\frac1{z}}}{z^{m+1}}=-\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^m\frac1{z^{m+1}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{n!z^n}=-\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^m}{n!}\frac1{z^{m+n+1}}.$$ Since $m+n+1=0$ if and only if $m=0$ and $n=0,$ we have that $$-\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^m}{n!}\frac1{z^{m+n+1}}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{n!}\frac1{z^{n+1}}-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^m}{n!}\frac1{z^{m+n+1}}=-\frac1{z}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n!}\frac1{z^{n+1}}-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^m}{n!}\frac1{z^{m+n+1}}.$$ Therefore, the residue of the integrand is $-1.$

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! So, if I understand correctly, for cases like this it would be correct to assume $|z| = 3$ for the Laurent series calculation as well? (as mentioned in my comment on the answer above)

Comment: @MateiRadu Yes. Notice that the integrand has two singularities: $0$ and $2.$ While $2$ is a simple pole, $0$ is actually an essential singularity. However, the Laurent expansion I presented in this answer is valid for $|z|\gt2,$ which is the region of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,2\}$ in which the contour $|z|=3$ is contained. Therefore, this is the Laurent expansion you care about. You always must make sure the contour of integration is contained in the region where the Laurent expansion converges.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I have given it some thought and it makes sense that it would be that way since the integration itself only happens for those values.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be aware that the integrand has two singularities inside the integration contour: $z=0$ and $z=2$. You'll find out that $z=2$ is a pole.

Trouble comes when calculating the residue at $z=0$, because you can show that $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} f(z)$ does not exist by taking different curves in the complex plane. Therefore, $z=0$ is an essential singularity, and the only way to find it's residue is through it's Laurent series expansion at $0$... and it's not an easy task due to the $2-z$ denominator.

You can make the change of variables $w=\frac{1}{z}$, but keep in mind that in $\mathbb{C}$, that change of variables is also an inversion transformation. It will map not only the function from the $z$ to the $w$ complex plane, but also the curve and it's orientation, and the singularities it now has in it's interior (such as the "point at infinty" $z=\infty$ which is mapped to $w=0$ as a new singularity you need to take care of).

See if you can work it out from here.

Comment: I did think of trying to calculate the Laurent series of $ f(z) $, however I got stuck because of the $ 2-z $ denominator as you mentioned. Would it be correct to assume $ |z|=3 $ for the Laurent series calculation or would I need to take into account both $ |z|>2 $ and $ |z|<2 $?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what do you mean with using $|z|=3$ for the Laurent series, because it is a curve, and for a series you need an open disk or annulus. Nevertheless, to see the residue of the singularity $z=0$ you would need a series expansion centered at $z=0$ AND it's region of convergence should be $0<|z|<2$ for this particular exercise.